# SVG line animation not working using anime.js

Tags: javascript, svg, anime.js

I have the following SVG in my HTML:

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="simple-line.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="-46.428571"
     inkscape:cy="520"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="705"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
       d="M 62.857143,492.3622 660,495.21935"
       id="path4136"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I want to create a line formation animation and so I use the following code snippet:

```
var lineDrawing = anime({
  targets: '#path4136',
  strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
  easing: 'easeInOutSine',
  duration: 1500,
  delay: function(el, i) { return i * 250 },
  direction: 'alternate',
  loop: true
});
```

I am using [anime.js](http://animejs.com/documentation/#lineDrawing) and I basically copied the code from one of the demos **[HERE](http://animejs.com/documentation/#lineDrawing)**.

The animation just won't work in my demo, I mean, the line will not form.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please make your snippet or jsfiddle, what's wrong?

Comment: set `stroke-dasharray:600` in the path style.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't anime.js working in my browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198703/why-isnt-anime-js-working-in-my-browser)