# Why isn't anime.js working in my browser?

Tags: javascript, html, anime.js

For some reason my anime.js isn't working in my browser, but when I give my code to people I know online, it works just fine for them.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="CSStransforms">
  <div class="square el"></div>
</div>
```

and yes, I have linked the cdn ->

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

and here's my JAVASCRIPT code:

```
var CSStransforms = anime({
  targets: '#CSStransforms .el',
  translateX: 250,
  scale: 2,
  rotate: '1turn'
});
```

here's all my code: https://codepen.io/sadsada/pen/GxKePJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to load your `main.js` at the *end* of the `body` tag, so the DOM has been loaded by the time your script executes.  If you put it in the `head` (above the `body`), the DOM has not loaded your elements yet, so `anime.js` doesn't find them.

This is why the codepen works but your own site didn't.  The codepen loads the DOM before executing your scripts.